# How to get rid of warning "Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code..."

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code that shows the warning...

> Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an
> additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider
> alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to
> 'Configure'.

[image]

Here is an abbreviated snippet from `ConfigureServices` that shows how this is being used.  Basically I need to resolve the AdminDbContext to pass it to the Initialize routine.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AdminDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer("config settings here"));

        CustomerConnectionStrings.Instance.Initialize(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<AdminDbContext>());
    }
```

What do I need to do to get rid of this warning?

I have seen other posts that show how to do this, but I am not making the connection for my specific use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I believe this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

I would advise following the suggestions in the warning

> Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'.

```
//...

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddDbContext<AdminDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer("config settings here"));

    //...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, AdminDbContext adminDb) {

    CustomerConnectionStrings.Instance.Initialize(adminDb);

    //...
}
```

Comment: Have no idea why I didn't make the connection to the actual Configure method.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

@Nkosi answer is a correct but in the case someone is looking for an alternative you can get any service from the app:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, AdminDbContext adminDb) {

    CustomerConnectionStrings.Instance.Initialize(App.ApplicationServices.GetService<IMyService>());

    //...
}
```

And another option for anyone who comes across this. Sometimes its better to work with singletons rather than static classes:
When you intialize `CustomerConnectionStrings` you will request AdminDBContext and pass it there.